# How to color a bar with Morris.js when the value is higher or lower then 70

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, morris.js

I founded this question here on stackoverflow:
[Varying bar colors with morris.js bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763825/varying-bar-colors-with-morris-js-bar-chart)

I want if the data in bar B is higher or lower then 70 to change it color.

I only can't figure out what I am doing wrong over here to make it work?

here is my code:

```
new Morris.Bar({
element: 'bar-example',
gridTextColor: '#00ff55',
data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
],
barColors : function(row, series, type) {
    if(data.b <70) return ['black', 'white'];
    else if(data.b >= 70) return ['white', 'black'];
},
xkey: 'y',
ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

Comment: `varColors` -> `barColors` ? You might also consider using `>= 70`, just in case `data.b` is equal to `70`. Also wrap `#00ff55` in quotes.

Comment: I did what your suggestions where but it looks like I can't acces the data b colom?

I was playing with it on: http://jsbin.com/cekecowiti/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `barColors` function, you need to look at the `series.key` value to determine which bar you are dealing with.  After that, you can return values as needed.
Let's say you want bars in series B to be red if they are below 70, otherwise blue.  Bars in series A are always green.
Your barColors function then would look something like this:

```
barColors: function(row, series, type) {
  if(series.key == 'b')
  {
    if(row.y < 70)
      return "red";
    else
      return "blue";  
  }
  else
  {
    return "green";
  }
}
```

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bicusapara/1/edit?html,js,output) for an illustration of this.