# Moris charts alternating colours for bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

Im currently making use of the Morris Bar chart and its working quite nicely.

Im having a problem with making the bars alternate in colour from 2 defined colours.

```
if( $("#publication-chart").length)
{
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'publication-chart',
  data: financeChartData,
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Total'],
  barColors: ['#FF0000','#000000','#FF0000','#000000','#FF0000']
});
}
```

in my code, i'm trying to alternate from red to black, but it only appears to show in red every time.

Ive also tried to have the colour of the chart come from the data array, but cant seem to get greater control over the bars in the chart

Comment: possible duplicate of [Varying bar colors with morris.js bar chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763825/varying-bar-colors-with-morris-js-bar-chart)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to barColors to override the default behavior.  Try something like this to alternate the colors of the bars:

```
barColors: function(row, series, type) {
  if(row.x % 2 == 0)
    return '#FF0000';
  else
    return '#000000';
}
```

This [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qaqidasofu/1/edit?html,js,output) illustrates a working example.