# Different colors for Morris Bar: (UNIQUE)

Tags: java, jquery, jstl, morris.js

I am trying to display a morris bar graph using two colors which represent the state of the items (bars). For example, lets say I have 5 members (A, B, C, D, E). On the left side I have their heights. The javascript code that accomplishes this for me is the following.

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'members-chart',
    data: [
        <c:forEach items="${Members}" var="member">
            {
                member_name: "${member.name}",
                height: "${member.height}",
                active: "${member.active}"
            },
        </c:forEach>
            ],
    xkey: 'member_name',
    ykeys: ['height'],
    labels: ['Height'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

Now you will see that I have placed **active: "${member.active}"** in there however it isn't really doing anything. I would like to change the color based on whatever value this is. For example, if the memberA.active = true, the color should be Blue and if memberB.active = false, the color should be grey. I am unsure if I can somehow use barColors functions to solve my issue but believe me that I have tried it.

also looked at [Varying bar colors with morris.js bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763825/varying-bar-colors-with-morris-js-bar-chart)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Just point me in the right direction! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data array is invalid since you add a comma after the last entry. Use `varStatus` on `forEach` and check for the [last iteration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast()) to set the comma.

```
        <c:forEach items="${Members}" var="member" varStatus="status">
            {
                member_name: "${member.name}",
                height: "${member.height}",
                active: "${member.active}"
            }${!status.last ? ',' : ''}
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. However, this doesn't help me with my question. Also, it still works fine with it so why go through the extra unnecessary work?

Comment: No problem. You should be a step further now.